# Search for header, select column, Insert (not paste) into another sheet

Tags: insert, copy, columnheader

As described above, I have some code that I have used in the past to paste columns based on searching for a certain header, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to adapt it to insert rather than paste.

Essentially this will be used to create a summary sheet, the columns may vary in size in the future and so I need to insert them to avoid overwriting values that originate from other sheets in the workbook.

There is almost certainly a better way of doing it than adapting the below but any help is much appreciated.

I've copied the original code I based mine on below.

```
Sub CopyColumnByTitle()

Dim t As Range

'Find "Name" in Row 1
  With Sheets(2).Rows(1)
   Set t = .Find("SEX", lookat:=xlPart)
'If found, copy the column to Sheet 2, Column A
'If not found, present a message
 If Not t Is Nothing Then
    Columns(t.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
      Destination:=Sheets(3).Range("A1")
   Else: MsgBox "Title Not Found"
 End If
 End With
 End Sub
```

Cheers